# How can I get a value from the line chart using selenium webdriver to compare

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can I get a value from the line chart using selenium web driver to compare?

I am using selenium web driver for automation. And I need to compare the line chart values with expected? I would appreciate if anyone answers for this. Please review it.

Comment: Is the line chart an image ?

Comment: No its a trend chart generated corresponding to the given value

Comment: HTML page content would have helped here. Please provide it.